OpenAI API error: How do I fix error 404 when I connect WhatsApp chatbot to OpenAI API?
How to fix the error in this code
const axios = require('axios');
const { API_KEY_OPEN_AI } = require('../config');

const ChatAIHandler = async (text, msg) => {

    const cmd = text.split('/');

    if (cmd.length < 2) {
        return msg.reply('Format Salah. ketik *#ask/your question*');
    }

    msg.reply('sedang diproses, tunggu bentar ya.');

    const question = cmd[1];
    const response = await ChatGPTRequest(question)

    if (!response.success) {
        return msg.reply(response.message);
    }

    return msg.reply(response.data);
}


const ChatGPTRequest = async (text) => {

    const result = {
        success: false,
        data: "Aku gak tau",
        message: "",
    }

    return await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://api.openai.com/v1/completions',
        data: {
            model: "text-davinci-003",
            prompt: text,
            max_tokens: 1000,
            temperature: 0
        },
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept-Language": "in-ID",
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${API_KEY_OPEN_AI}`,
        },
    })
    .then((response) => {
        if (response.status == 200) {

            const { choices } = response.data;

            if (choices && choices.length) {
                result.success = true;
                result.data = choices[0].text;
            }

        } else {
            result.message = "Failed response";
        }

        return result;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        result.message = "Error : " + error.message;
        return result;
    });
}

module.exports = {
    ChatAIHandler
}

I changed the latest API key, but the problem was not solved.

Problem 1: You're using the deprecated model
You are using the following API endpoint:
https://api.openai.com/v1/completions

This is the OpenAI Completions API endpoint. But later on, you want to use the text-davinci-003 model. This model was deprecated on January 4, 2024.
Simply replace the text-davinci-003 model with gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct, babbage-002, or davinci-002. All three work with the OpenAI Completions API endpoint.
Problem 2: You're extracting the response incorrectly
Also, make sure you are extracting the response correctly. See an example response:
{
  "id": "cmpl-uqkvlQyYK7bGYrRHQ0eXlWi7",
  "object": "text_completion",
  "created": 1589478378,
  "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct",
  "system_fingerprint": "fp_44709d6fcb",
  "choices": [
    {
      "text": "\n\nThis is indeed a test",
      "index": 0,
      "logprobs": null,
      "finish_reason": "length"
    }
  ],
  "usage": {
    "prompt_tokens": 5,
    "completion_tokens": 7,
    "total_tokens": 12
  }
}

The correct way to extract the response is the following:
response.choices[0].text


I tried to change the model and then I got the  error code 429, what's wrong?

@GalangCakrabuana You need to upgrade to a paid plan. See my past answer.
